# MATLAB Restart function instead of return(cancel)

Tags: matlab

I've been looking over, but I don't think it exists.
There is return to essentially force close your function, which is nice, but in my current script, I want if it does something incorrectly, to instead return to the start of the sub function that it exists in.

Are there any functions that exist already to do that, or will I have to make a system in order to let myself do that?

Comment: looks like you need to implement a `while` structure to me...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `return`, [`error`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html) out of the function when something is "done incorrectly", then use [`try`/`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) in a `while`-loop:

```
while 1
    try
        myFunction();
        break; % if myFunction() was successful, this will exit the while loop
    catch
        % do some sort of processing here, then go back to the while loop
    end
end
```

The `catch` portion of the `try`/`catch` block will execute only if `myFunction()` had an error. `return` implies the function succeeded (whether or not it gave correct output is a different issue entirely).

---

Alternatively, you could put your function in a `while`-loop as suggested by @natan. Return some sort of error code, then check for that error code in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `while 1` loop to wrap around the whole function and `continue` when you want to restart the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it if you are not looking for error handling, but just outcome handling

```
finishedSuccesfully = false
while ~finishedSuccesfully 
    output = myFunction();
    finishedSuccesfully = evaluateoutput(output);
end
```